# Why is it that when I install a new npm package I have to run "docker-compose down" followed by "docker-compose up --build"?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, node-modules

Shouldn't `docker-compose up --build` suffice?

Here's our Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine

# Set app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install git in order to allow installing
# npm packages from Github
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache git

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV development

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And our docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://admin:app@mongo:27017/app?authSource=admin
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      # More info on the node_modules volume at:
      # http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
      # under "The node_modules Volume Trick"
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    # Run nodemon with legacy watch
    # https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting
    # Ignore public/ because generating documentation programatically
    # on startup was causing an infinite loop
    command: ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --legacy-watch --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 --ignore public/
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: app
    volumes:
      # Using a named volume because windows doesn't deal well with mounting local folders
      - app-api-mongodb-storage:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: app
    depends_on:
      - mongo

volumes:
  # Database named module has to be declared globally
  app-api-mongodb-storage:
```

From what I can tell, `docker-compose down` should delete the node_modules volume, because it is created by `docker-compose up`.

Is there some kind of caching that is preventing package.json from being refreshed unless `docker-compose --build` is used in order to explicitly rebuild the Docker image?

Comment: This depends on how your application is packaged and run using docker. What are you trying to do ? You'll need to add your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and details about your use case, to your question, so that we can help you.

Comment: @lbndev I'm just trying to understand how Docker handles installing npm packages when package.json changes, given our setup. I just updated the question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

With your current setup, at image build time you are running `npm install` which creates and populates a node_modules folder inside the image.

When you start a container from this image, with your current docker-compose.yml file, docker creates a new randomly-named volume, copies the content from the image's node_modules folder into this new volumes, and mounts the volume on the node_modules folder.

Your update to package.json will be visible within the container, because you are mounting your current folder as /usr/src/app (this hides the version packaged in the image).

You haven't mentioned how you are running `npm install` after updating your package.json file. My guess is that you are running it directly on your host. If correct, this is your problem : it won't work, because your node_modules folder is bound to the docker volume, not your local folder. You need to run `npm install` inside the container, by doing something like `docker-compose exec web npm install`.

Comment: I am not running npm install at all, I am expecting `npm install` to be run from the Dockerfile when the image is being created.

I thought since `docker-compose down` deletes the image, `docker-compose up` would have to rebuild it and would run `npm install`, but apparently it won't unless you use `--build`.

Comment: No, docker-compose down shuts down the containers but doesn't delete neither the images or the containers (check with `docker images` and `docker ps -a`). Since your `npm install` instruction is in your Dockerfile, which is only processed when the images are built, it is not re-run when you simply call `docker-compose up`. This instruction starts containers from existing images, so unless you are forcing these images to be rebuilt, there will be no call to install.

Comment: Right! The docs are a bit confusing - it doesn't delete all of that by default https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/